# How can I test a library that has <>-based #includes on Linux without "installing" it?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, fedora

I am trying to perform some work on a large C open source software library on Linux (specifically, Fedora 35). One issue I am having is that the system that I am using to do the work already has the library "installed" (and it cannot be uninstalled, because the system requires it to run) and therefore, what I've done is build the version to be tested in its own dir and not "installed" it to the system.

The main problem is that when I write a testing program, I need to compile and link it against the version of the library that I have downloaded and built locally, **not the one that is installed to the system.** So, I've used commands like this:

`gcc -g3 ./my_test_program.c -o my_test_program -L/home/user/testing/glib2/usr/lib64 -lgio -I/home/user/testing/glib2/glib-2.70/gio`

where, I've specified the .so and include path manually. This works, except that now I get errors because in this case, there are other files inside of `glib` which use syntax like `<gio/giotypes.h>`, so the compiler is looking for a **system installed <gio/giotypes.h>** when in fact, the header file is equivalent to `../gio/gio.h` relative to the location of the source file. Therefore, either the compiler ends up using the system installed dependency, or, in my case, throws an error which says `fatal error: gio/giotypes.h: no such file or directory` because I don't even have the `-devel` package installed, intentionally. If I did install the version of the `-devel` package, then I would have a mismatch between the `-devel` package and the main system package installed on the system, plus it doesn't make sense as that would just try to use the system-installed version of the library that I *am not* trying to use.

What is the proper way to compile & link a program like I am trying to do on linux with a different version of a system-wide dependency without installing it? It seems that there are files in the library (in this, glib) which expect it to be installed. Is there a way to override this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell). :-(  When this sort of thing gets extreme, most people throw up their hands and move to a chroot or Docker or similar sort of sandboxed environment.

Comment: Perhaps you should replace `-I/home/user/testing/glib2/glib-2.70/gio` with `-I/home/user/testing/glib2/glib-2.70`?

Comment: Have you tried using the library's own build system to install the development files into a staging directory (set by the DESTDIR environment variable)? You can then set PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR to that directory while running `pkgconf` (or `pkg-config`) to pick up the compiler options to use the staging version of the library. E.g. `gcc -g3 $(PKG_CONFIG_SYS_ROOT=/path/to/staging pkgconf -cflags gio-2.0) my_test_program.c -o my_test_program $(PKG_CONFIG_SYS_ROOT=/path/to/staging pkgconf -libs gio-2.0)`

Comment: @IanAbbott this is a nice idea and I am giving it a try. The only hiccup I've run into now is handling the /include stuff, aka header files that would usually be in the `-devel` package. Would you suggest also installing that -devel package into the `/path/to/staging` using e.g. `--installroot=` on dnf? At present, I still cannot actually link the library due to missing header file errors when I try to compile as described above.